# Display/Visualize JSON with arbitrary depth in an Angular2 HTML Template

Tags: json, angular

I've a json structure with an arbitrary deep (1 to n) and in this structure there are other recurring structures. How can I show all elements (keys and values) in an html template?

**EDIT: I want to iterate over all keys and values**

As an example I can give following structure:

```
{
  "contract": [{
    "part a": [{
      "x": "foo"
    }, {
      "y": [{
        "i": "one"
      }, {
        "ii": "two"
      }, {
        "iii": [{
          "part a": [{
            "x": "bar"
          }, {
            "y": [{
              "i": [{
                "part a": [{
                  "x": "nix"
                }]
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "part b": [{
      "x": "any"
    }, {
      "y": [{
        "i": {
          "part a": [{
            "x": "some"
          }]
        }
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Here as picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with a recursive directive and no one has helped me :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#-jsonpipe-) to display JSON data in your template:

```
<div>{{data | json}}</div>
```

Comment: I want to iterate over the json structure and add/modify key and values.

Comment: So you need to use a `for(let property in jsonObj)` where `jsonObj` is an object created using `JSON.parse(yourJson)`.